# A few queries on HTML 5

Tags: html, iis, iis-6

Can I host HTML 5 application in IIS 6.0? 
If not which version of IIS supports HTML hosting?
Which editor can be used for HTML 5 development?

Comment: HTML5 Development? Have a look at *anything that edits text*. Notepad, Visual Studio, Dreamweaver, Coda, Notepad+, Eclipse, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html 5 is client-side technology, so you can use any versin of iis.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is just a new standard for the HTMLanguage, which browsers interpret differently and this is has more features. HTML5 is not really a server-side thing, if you can host HTML you can host HTML5. Read this:

http://brolik.com/blog/make-sure-to-code-my-site-in-html5/

Comment: New draft spec, not standard. Though things are fuzzier these days.

Comment: It's still a new standard. (Not fully implemented yet, but will be a full standard eventually).